# Remote debug a standalone java application in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug a standalone java application. I have done all that was recommended by IntelliJ, that is to add and edit a remote configuration on IntelliJ and added the recommended parameters:-

```
agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

But when I run the debugger I get Unable to open debugger port:

> java.net.ConnectionException "Connection refused: connect"

Is there anything I need to on application side:that how will the application know on which port to attach to?How can I make my application listens on the specified port?

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the remote system? iptables? Windows firewall? Are the two machines on the same network? Is there a router between them that could be filtering packets?

Comment: Firewall is OK, I checked, IDEA(IntelliJ) is a exception - that it will allow to communicate, both the machines are in same network, but if I run the application on my own machine, still the same issue.

Comment: The jdwp string is for the remote side to be debugged. In Intellij you must configure the remote connection for the project and specify the port number (5005).  I use Eclipse so I don't know where this is in IDEA.

Comment: @DocSoft Did you get any clue?